# Nested Collapsibles with Materialize

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I am working on a [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) project at the minute which uses [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/). I can implement [Collapsible](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) elements fine

[image]

but when I try and create nested Collapsibles it doesn't look right (notice the spacing above and below, not to mention the lack of an indent which would normally indicate a nested list). Is this a shortcoming of Materialize or is my attempt flawed?

[image]

I am trying to achieve it with the sample code

```html
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
                </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How did you get the nested `collapsible-header/body` to work? Because with me they dont even open

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and was able to nest collapsibles by doing any of the following:

1. Wrap the nested collapsible in a grid row and column that spans the entire width of the containing element, or
2. Wrap the nested collapsible in a div with class = "container", or
3. Wrap the nested collapsible in a container div, a row div, and a col div (a combination of 1 and 2 above), or
4. Wrap the nested collapsible in a div styled with a padding of whatever value you want

Performing #1 above makes the nested collapsible just slightly smaller with a little padding so that it is slightly indented.  Doing #2 or #3 makes the nested collapsible considerably smaller and centers it, resulting in a much larger indent.  #4 gives you the most control over how you want the nesting to look.

I would think that the 4th way, styling with padding, is the best way to implement this.

I've modified the original HTML to demonstrate these methods:

```html
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
 <li>
  <div class="collapsible-header">
   <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12">
     <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
      <li>
       <div class="collapsible-header">
        <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
       <div class="collapsible-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="collapsible-header">
        <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
       <div class="collapsible-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="collapsible-header">
        <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
       <div class="collapsible-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="collapsible-header">
   <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
   <div class="container">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="collapsible-header">
   <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12 m12">
      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
       <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
         <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
         <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
         <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <div class="collapsible-header">
   <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Fourth</div>
  <div class="collapsible-body">
   <div style="padding:25px">
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
       <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I've also created a codepen of the above that demonstrates nested collapsibles, see link below:

[Nested Collapsibles in Materialize](http://codepen.io/jasonpaul/pen/WrjQQg?editors=100)

Comment: How can I remove the borders in the nested collapsibles ?

Answer (score 4):

Collapsibles were not styled with nested collapsibles in mind. You can add custom css to help style this by styling only the inner collapsible:

```
.collapsible .collapsible {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can also play around with the padding or borders to help make it clearer that it is another collapsible inside of the outer collapsible.